# Can I get first child and last child in this structure using css? Something dynamic, the number of button can be increase decrease

Tags: html, css

Can I get first child and last child in this structure using css? Something dynamic, the number of button can be increase decrease.

```html
<div  class="z-vlayout-inner">
                <button type="button" id="f6wP40">Textures</button>
                </div>
                <div  class="z-vlayout-inner">
                <button type="button" id="f6wP50">Special Diets</button>
                </div>
                <div class="z-vlayout-inner">
                <button type="button" id="f6wP60" >Allergies</button>
                </div>
                <div  class="z-vlayout-inner">
                <button type="button" id="f6wP70" >Dislikes</button>
                </div>
```

Comment: Unless you have a wrapper around that lot...you can't using `first or last child`. - https://jsfiddle.net/hjqfyjd9/1/

Answer (score 2):

use css selector `:first-of-type` and `:last-of-type`

```css
.z-vlayout-inner:first-of-type button, .z-vlayout-inner:last-of-type button{
  background-color:yellow
  }
```

```html
<div  class="z-vlayout-inner">
                <button type="button" id="f6wP40">Textures</button>
                </div>
                <div  class="z-vlayout-inner">
                <button type="button" id="f6wP50">Special Diets</button>
                </div>
                <div class="z-vlayout-inner">
                <button type="button" id="f6wP60" >Allergies</button>
                </div>
                <div  class="z-vlayout-inner">
                <button type="button" id="f6wP70" >Dislikes</button>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont think so. CSS is for styling purposes only. You can get the child of an element by using the `childNodes` property using javascript. In your case, if you want to get the first and last child of your body element, you can use `document.body.firstChild.innerHTML;` and `document.body.childNodes[document.body.childNodes.length-1].innerHTML;` respectively